# Removing all AzureAD group memberships for a user

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

So I work in a hybrid enviroment.  I have a script that I put together that will strip all their memberships in AD and I want to add onto it the ability to do the same for AzureAD.

```
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user | foreach-object {Remove-AzureADGroupMember -MemberId $user -ObjectId $_.ObjectID}
```

This snippet is causing me problems.  It tries to do the foreach but it doesn't seem able to get the $_.objectID from the UserMembership cmdlet so it errors out.

```
Remove-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing RemoveGroupMember 
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported referenced-object resource identifier for link property 'members'.
RequestId: b1975588-c678-4183-b037-a52f8772b08f
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 09 Jun 2022 00:02:42 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

I tried to seperate it out and do

```
$groups=Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user
$groups | foreach-object {Remove-AzureADGroupMember -MemberId $user -ObjectId $groups.ObjectID}
```

And it gave me this error

```
Remove-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ObjectId'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I am still pretty new to powershell so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The second snippet is fine, but you just need to change `-ObjectId $groups.ObjectID` for `-ObjectId $_.ObjectID`. That should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to run the same script in my environment and got same error as below:***

[image]

***As suggested by ***[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)*** in the comments, when I modified the code like below, got response successfully:***

```
$user = 'Your_user_objectid' 
$groups=Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user
$groups | foreach-object {Remove-AzureADGroupMember -MemberId $user -ObjectId $_.ObjectID}
```

**Response:**

[image]